# React-Select --- How to get default value and overwrite the default value when user selected another option

Tags: reactjs, react-select

Below is my react-select, *field.value* is the value that return from API.
For example, *field.value* is **'Active'**.

So, my frontend will show **'Active'** and this is what I want, but if I select another option which is **'Inactive'**, it wont change the value and keep displaying the option **'Active'**.

My question is how to change the default value(**'Active'**) to another selected value(**'Inactive'**)?

Thanks

```
    const methods = useFormContext();
    const [selectedOption, setSelectedOption] = useState("none");
    const options = [
        { value: 'Active', label: 'Active' },
        { value: 'Inactive', label: 'Inactive' }
    ]
    const handleTypeSelect = e => {
        
        setSelectedOption(e.value);
    };
    return (
        <div>
            <Controller
                name="inventory_source_status"
                control={control}
                render={({ field }) => (
                    <Select 
                        {...field}
                        id="inventory_source_status"
                        className="mt-8 mb-16"
                        placeholder="Inventory Source Status *"
                        options={options}
                        onChange={handleTypeSelect}
                        value = {{ value: field.value, label: field.value } || ''}
                        required
                        error={!!errors.inventory_source_status}
                        helperText={errors?.inventory_source_status?.message}
                    />
                )}
            />
        </div>
        
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use
defaultValue={{ value: field.value, label: field.description}}